# Strict mode in android 2.2

Tags: android, android-strictmode

I have target sdk set as 3.2 and min sdk as 2.2, how can I use strictmode in my application, as I understand it is introduced but cannot really understand how to start using it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My suggestion is two-fold:

First, add some baseline [StrictMode code](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) to your [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)'s `onCreate()`.  This lets you apply StrictMode to your entire app in an easy fashion (though you could put this code anywhere for more specific testing).  There's good sample code in the StrictMode docs.

Second, detect the version of the SDK before trying to use StrictMode.  This way, you only use StrictMode in API versions 9 or above - if you don't do this check, you'll crash your app on older versions of Android.  You can easily detect the SDK version by looking at [Build.VERSION.SDK_INT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT).

Optionally, you may want to only enable StrictMode when you're testing.  How you do this is up to you, though [I've written up one solution for this in the past](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2011/04/detecting-keystore-signature-in-code.html).

Comment: I don't know why, but [solution #2 in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18335031/2423194) didn't work in `Application.onCreate()` (got `NetworkOnMainThreadException`), even though my logging code got printed indicating that the methods were called. But it did work if I put it in my main activity's `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 19):

**`StrictMode.ThreadPolicy`** was introduced since API Level 9 and the default thread policy had been changed since API Level 11, which in short, does not allow network operation

(eg: `HttpClient` and `HttpUrlConnection`) get executed on UI thread. If you do this, you get **`NetworkOnMainThreadException`**.

You can easily solve this error By two ways:-

1. The recommended way of solving this is by Using `anAsyncTask` so
   that the network request does not block the UI thread.
2. Alternatively, you can override this thread policy by adding the
   below code into your main activity’s onCreate() method.

> ```
> if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
>     StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = 
>     new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();      
>         StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
>  }
> ```

Hope this is helpful to you..

Comment: Merry Xmas! Learning about strictmode finally sheds the light on those errors! Time to learn async thingies! :)

Answer (score 2):

Set the Android Manifest to something like this.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" android:maxSdkVersion="16"/>
```

Use the below code in the onCreate Method.

```
int SDK_INT = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

if (SDK_INT>8){

StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

}
```

Note: Disable the warning as you are already checking which version of the Android is going to use this code.

This Code will be activated if the Android version is higher than Android 2.2

Comment: Shouldn't it be detectAll? Sorry the official Android documentation is fuzzy as usual.

Answer (score 1):

This is really helpful for How to use StrictMode in App?
Check this..
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_strictmode/

Comment: Use this Link **http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk_strictmode--mobile-7581** It will helps you

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following link on how to use it.
Set it up on the onCreate of the relevant component or the Application

[Strict Mode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html)

Answer (score 0):

It helped in resolving the issue by checking the api level and then executing strict mode.