# How to use setbackground property with URL

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to know that, How can I use the Url to set the background of a particular view.
Something like this:

```
TextView someview;
someview.setbackground(url).
```

Suppose I am getting that URL from Firebase Database through a getter method in my model class.

Can someone help me clearly understand this...

Actually I am trying to load user status from Firebase node that I have created.
Below is the whole code and explanation:
The problem is in adapter class, and I commented there please check...

**The Node I want to achieve from firebase:**
[image]

**Model class for that node:**

package com.example.sociapp;

```
public class Status {

    String backgrounduri, date, fullname, profileimage, e, time, uid, userstatus;
    long textcolor, textsize;
    public Status ( )
    {

    }

    public Status(String backgrounduri, String date, String fullname, String profileimage, long textcolor, long textsize, String time, String uid, String userstatus)
    {
        this.backgrounduri = backgrounduri;
        this.date = date;
        this.fullname = fullname;
        this.profileimage = profileimage;
        this.textcolor = textcolor;
        this.textsize = textsize;
        this.time = time;
        this.uid = uid;
        this.userstatus = userstatus;
    }

    public String getBackgrounduri() {
        return backgrounduri;
    }

    public void setBackgrounduri(String backgrounduri) {
        this.backgrounduri = backgrounduri;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getFullname() {
        return fullname;
    }

    public void setFullname(String fullname) {
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }

    public String getProfileimage() {
        return profileimage;
    }

    public void setProfileimage(String profileimage) {
        this.profileimage = profileimage;
    }

    public long getTextcolor() {
        return textcolor;
    }

    public void setTextcolor(long textcolor) {
        this.textcolor = textcolor;
    }

    public long getTextsize() {
        return textsize;
    }

    public void setTextsize(long textsize) {
        this.textsize = textsize;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getUserstatus() {
        return userstatus;
    }

    public void setUserstatus(String userstatus) {
        this.userstatus = userstatus;
    }
}
```

**Below is the adapter class:**

```
public class StatusAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StatusAdapter.viewHolder> {

   java.util.List<String> statuskeyList;
    List<Status> SList;
    Context context;

    DatabaseReference ClickstatusRef;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    public StatusAdapter(List<String> statuskeyList, List<Status> SList, Context context)
    {
        this.statuskeyList = statuskeyList;
        this.SList = SList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

         View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.all_user_status_layout, parent, false);
        return new viewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder holder, int position) {

        Status status = SList.get(position);
        String statusKey = statuskeyList.get(position);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        final String   CurrentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        Picasso.get().load(status.getProfileimage()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(holder.Profileimage);
        holder.FullName.setText(status.getFullname());
        holder.Date.setText(status.getDate());
        holder.Time.setText(status.getTime());
        holder.UserStatus.setText(status.getUserstatus());

        ClickstatusRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Status").child(statusKey);
       /* String name = status.getBackgrounduri();
        int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(id);*/
       try {
           int status_background = Integer.parseInt(status.getBackgrounduri());
           holder.UserStatus.setBackgroundResource(status_background);
          }
       catch (NumberFormatException e)
              {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
//I tried all the code for setting background commented and not commented but no use
```

//The problem is here, and here I am setting background Url that I am getting from firebase. I tried all the code  you can see in here commented and none commented
       //  `holder.UserStatus.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(context.getResources().getIdentifier("SociApp",   "getBackground",context.getPackageName())));`

```
    int status_color = (int) status.getTextcolor();
    holder.UserStatus.setTextColor(status_color);
    int Text_Size = (int)  status.getTextsize()/ 3 ;
    holder.UserStatus.setTextSize(Text_Size);


    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

         ClickstatusRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
             @Override
             public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                 if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                 {
                     String statusUserId = dataSnapshot.child("uid").getValue().toString();

                     if (statusUserId.equals(CurrentUserId))
                     {
                         View mview = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
                         TextView Message = mview.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
                         Button OkBtn = mview.findViewById(R.id.dialog_btn);
                         AlertDialog.Builder mbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.mydialog);
                         mbuilder.setView(mview);
                         String message = "Do you want to delete your status!";
                         Message.setText(message);
                         OkBtn.setText("Do it");
                         OkBtn.setWidth(100);
                         final Dialog dialog = mbuilder.create();
                         dialog.show();

                         OkBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                             @Override
                             public void onClick(View v) {

                                 ClickstatusRef.removeValue();
                                 dialog.dismiss();
                                 SendUserToLoadstatusActivity();
                             }
                         });
                     }

                     else
                     {
                         Toast.makeText(context, "You just long clicked the status", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }
                 }
             }

             @Override
             public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

             }
         });

            return true;
        }
    });

}

private void SendUserToLoadstatusActivity()
{
    Intent MainIntent = new Intent(context, LoadStatusActivity.class);
    MainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
   context.startActivity(MainIntent);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return SList.size();
}

public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private CircleImageView Profileimage;
    private TextView FullName;
    private TextView Date,Time;
    private TextView UserStatus;

    public viewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);

        Profileimage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status_profile_image);
        FullName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status_user_name);
        Date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status_date);
        Time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status_time);
        UserStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.all_user_status);

    }
}
```

}

**Below I am passing data to arraylists from LoadStatusActivity:**

```
public class LoadStatusActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar mtoolbar;
    private TextView UserStatusButton;
    private RecyclerView StatusList;
    private ProgressBar ProgressCircular;

    private DatabaseReference StatusRef;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private List<Status> mUserStatus;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_load_status);

        mtoolbar = findViewById(R.id.status_page_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mtoolbar);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        StatusList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.all_users_status_list);
        ProgressCircular = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.status_progress_circular);

        StatusRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Status");

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Status");

        UserStatusButton = findViewById(R.id.status_post_btn);

        mUserStatus = new ArrayList();
        final List<String> Keys = new ArrayList<>();

        StatusList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        StatusList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        UserStatusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SendUserToStatusPostActivity( );
            }
        });

        Query sortStatusInDescendantOrder = StatusRef.orderByChild("counter");

        sortStatusInDescendantOrder.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                mUserStatus.clear();

                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        Keys.add(dataSnapshot1.getKey());

                        Status status = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Status.class);
                        mUserStatus.add(status);

                    }

                    StatusAdapter statusAdapter = new StatusAdapter( Keys, mUserStatus, LoadStatusActivity.this);
                    StatusList.setAdapter(statusAdapter);
                    ProgressCircular.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(LoadStatusActivity.this, "There is no post Exists! " + DatabaseError.PERMISSION_DENIED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ProgressCircular.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void SendUserToStatusPostActivity() {

        Intent StatusPostIntent = new Intent(LoadStatusActivity.this, StatusPostActivity.class);
        startActivity(StatusPostIntent);
    }
}
```

**The Output I am getting:**
[image]

but I want text with background not only text.and that background url is saved in **backgrounduri** as shown in first picture at the top. how to load it.
[image]

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to achieve here. Setting an url as a background of a `TextView` does not make much sense to me. Do you want to show the url as text in your `TextView`?

Comment: No, I upload an image to Firebase Storage, then download that image link from storage and put it in realtime database with child backgrounduri. now I want to set that image as a background of textView. throug the use of textview.setbackround(that Url)

Comment: Sir please I added alot of stuff, Now check it and answer if you can please.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19785099/get-image-from-url-and-set-as-relative-layout-background-on-android/52431888?

Comment: They are trying to convert a bitmap into drawable formate. where I am trying to convert a string into some formate that setbackground property accepts.

Comment: They download a `Bitmap` from a given URL and set the `Bitmap` as the background `Drawable` of a view. That's exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes it is, I did not notice it... super post as an answer that comment so that I can give you a vote thanks alot you are great. super duper

Comment: Why did you add an answer yourself instead of accepting mine?

Comment: Oh sorry, very sorry I vote for you and accept your answer. I did not try the answer here, I tried code from your link, and that works for me. So I pasted it here... so it may help someone else in future.

Comment: Its, fine. No worries :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to download the `Bitmap` from the given URL and set this `Bitmap` as the background `Drawable` of your `TextView`.

To download the `Bitmap` you have to add internet permission to your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

You can download your `Bitmap` from the given url like this:

```
try {
    // create url from string
    URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
    // connect to url
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.connect();
    // download image
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    # return myBitmap or do something else
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
```

To set this `Bitmap` as background of your `TextView` you have to convert it to a `Drawable` first by using:

```
// create drawable from bitmap
Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(myBitmap);
myTextView.setBackground(dr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from above link in comment.
For my problem I solved it by adding the below code in my adapter class at the place I commented above:

**Code peace I needed:**

```
 StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        try {
            URL url = new URL(status.backgrounduri);
            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(image);
            holder.UserStatus.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        int status_color = (int) status.getTextcolor();
        holder.UserStatus.setTextColor(status_color);
        int Text_Size = (int)  status.getTextsize()/ 3 ;
        holder.UserStatus.setTextSize(Text_Size);
```

We can do this by downloading the URL in String formate then convert it into Bitmap and then Convert that bitmap into drawable formate and set as background through the use of setbackground(the drawable);